# How to make NERDTree adjust view while navigating?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When expanding directories in NERDTree the contents are cutoff by the buffer frame, which require that I use keyboard commands to jump to the end of the line.

Example:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically shift the view frame to always have the current node in view?

Answer (score 0):

NERDTree's [documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt) lists all of its features and key mappings; if you can't find that mentioned there, it's not implemented yet.

I'm only aware of the related [toggle zoom mapping](https://https///github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/72c3656799289d4635520c28e17f737066ce19d6/doc/NERDTree.txt#L586) (default key: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) that lets you manually expand the side panel's width. Purely with Vim commands, if you position the cursor at the end of the file list via <kbd>$</kbd>, it will stay there when you navigate to other files, e.g. via <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd>. Also, there are commands like [`:help gm`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#gm) that you could automatically execute (e.g. on `CursorMoved`, installed via `:autocmd` in the NERDTree buffer).

If that isn't sufficient for you, suggest the feature via [NERDTree's issues](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues), or implement a patch yourself.